# Div append problem when height is larger that container

Tags: jquery, css

Can somebody suggest me solution for this behaviour. I have one `div id="container"` with `height="500px"` and I append couple new divs in that like `$('#conatiner).append('generated new div with some id and height');`. Problem is that when sum of inserted divs  is larger than 500px, my first inserted div become invisible ( `height=0px`). How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?I tried this setup:

CSS

```
#container{
    height:500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#mine{
      background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

</div>
<button id='button'>click</button>
```

JQuery

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var div = $('<div>', {height: '200px', id: 'mine'});
    $('#container').append(div);

});
```

and i couldn't replicate your problem.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/CHJWP/

Comment: What should I do for the parent container to grow with the append of new items?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez  
You simply augment the height of the container each time you append a new item. jsfiddle.net/CHJWP/2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it would disappear, it should just expand outside of the box.

Do you need to have the container div set to a height before you start appending? If not, I'd remove it.

If you want the container div to be a fixed height; add `overflow-y:auto;` to your css applied to #container this will add a scrollbar to your #container div when the content goes over 500px (think this still worked with jQuery).

Otherwise if the #container div can grow, I'd use `min-height` in the css on the #container this will push everything down as you add more and more.